# Guava ForwardingObject, Serializable and parameterless constructor

Tags: java, guava, serializable

From the javadoc of guava's [`ForwardingObject`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingObject.html):

> Although this class does not implement `Serializable`, a serializable
>   subclass may be created since this class has a parameter-less
>   constructor.

Why is a parameterless constructor needed for a class to be able to be `Serializable`? Am I misunderstanding something, or is this just an error in the javadoc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just means you can write:

```
class MyForwardingFoo extends ForwardingObject implements Serializable {
  //
}
```

and it'll be serializable despite `ForwardingObject` itself isn't serializable; mentioning empty constructor isn't probably the best wording there but from the language perspective it's a sufficient condition to achieve serializability. What's more important is the fact that `ForwardingObject` itself doesn't hold any non-serializable fields.